# Where can I find technical documentation for training in Ubuntu?

Tags: documentation, training

hello friends as might have documentation, written tests, ubuntu introductory material, to give talks to local users, I'm from Venezuela state falcon, or as part of a dedicated service technician specializing in ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

It's for 8.04, but much of the work should still be applicable.

If nothing else it will provide a great framework for you to get started:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Training